# Load image from external http URL using fo:external-graphic XSL

Tags: javascript, xml, pdf, xslt, pdf-generation

I'm trying to use load images using `fo:external-graphic` XSL.

I tried few sample code.

sample-1

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('abc.jpg')" width="340px" height="238px"/>
```

**If i use static image directly..then It's working**

sample-2

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('http://220.226.207.170/mcraftuat/storageservice?a=readfile&databasename=mco&blobkey=f251fcf9-afa1-49cb-9a48-093cc0af049f')" width="340px" height="238px"/>
```

Here i'm trying to load some external image using blobkey. But its not working.

sample-3

```
<fo:external-graphic src="220.226.207.170/mcraftuat/storageservice?a=readfile&databasename=mco&blobkey=f251fcf9-afa1-49cb-9a48-093cc0af049f" width="340px" height="238px"/>
```

Above code also not working.

Please guide or suggest better option or method to load image available on third party site.

Please note that, I'm trying to load this and generating PDF using XSL & XML.

Any more info needed please comment accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: Try second example with the \' . Just use a quote. You do not escape ' in xsl

Comment: @KevinBrown: I have removed from it and updated my question as well. Still its not working sample 2 and sample 3. Is there any other way?

Comment: you should escape '&' to '&amp;'

Comment: Yes, @JoelM.Lamsen advice is next. In fact you must not be using a XML editor to look at your content.